# PL Sql Creating Hierarcical ID

Tags: sql, oracle

i have this table without any hierarcy but its obvious it has a hierarcy like 100,100-01,100-01-01 ..

```
ID       ACCOUNT
3       100
4       100-01
5       100-01-01
6       100-01-01-001
7       100-01-01-006
8       100-01-01-271
9       100-01-01-272
10      100-01-01-273
11      100-01-16
12      100-01-16-420
13      100-02
14      100-02-01
15      100-02-01-001
16      100-02-01-271
17      100-02-01-272
```

i want to fill like this;  100-01 is child of 100 , 100-01-01 is child of 100-01 so ;

```
ID  H_ID     ACCOUNT
3           100
4   3       100-01
5   4       100-01-01
6   5       100-01-01-001
7   5       100-01-01-006
8   5       100-01-01-271
9   5       100-01-01-272
10  5       100-01-01-273
11  4       100-01-16
12  11      100-01-16-420
13  3       100-02
14  13      100-02-01
15  14      100-02-01-001
16  14      100-02-01-271
17  14      100-02-01-272
```

Thank you for your time...

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: i try with update but i got stuck

Comment: why is the first h_id 2, but there is not entry with id 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the 'parent' account with `substr` and `instr`:

```
select id, account, substr(account, 1, instr(account, '-', -1, 1) - 1)
from your_table;

        ID ACCOUNT       SUBSTR(ACCOUN
---------- ------------- -------------
         3 100                        
         4 100-01        100          
         5 100-01-01     100-01       
         6 100-01-01-001 100-01-01    
...
```

You can then (outer) join the table to itself using that value:

```
select t1.id, t2.id as h_id, t1.account
from your_table t1
left join your_table t2
on t2.account = substr(t1.account, 1, instr(t1.account, '-', -1, 1) - 1)
order by t1.id;
```

which with your sample data gives:

```
        ID       H_ID ACCOUNT      
---------- ---------- -------------
         3            100          
         4          3 100-01       
         5          4 100-01-01    
         6          5 100-01-01-001
         7          5 100-01-01-006
         8          5 100-01-01-271
         9          5 100-01-01-272
        10          5 100-01-01-273
        11          4 100-01-16    
        12         11 100-01-16-420
        13          3 100-02       
        14         13 100-02-01    
        15         14 100-02-01-001
        16         14 100-02-01-271
        17         14 100-02-01-272
```

There is no parent for ID 3 so it isn't clear why your expected result has 2 for that.

You could also extract the 'branch' and 'leaf' parts of the account if that's useful:

```
select t1.id, t2.id as h_id, t1.account,
  substr(t1.account, 1, instr(t1.account, '-', -1, 1) - 1) as branch,
  substr(t1.account, instr(t1.account, '-', -1, 1) + 1) as leaf
from your_table t1
left join your_table t2
on t2.account = substr(t1.account, 1, instr(t1.account, '-', -1, 1) - 1)
order by t1.id;

        ID       H_ID ACCOUNT       BRANCH        LEAF         
---------- ---------- ------------- ------------- -------------
         3            100                         100          
         4          3 100-01        100           01           
         5          4 100-01-01     100-01        01           
         6          5 100-01-01-001 100-01-01     001          
         7          5 100-01-01-006 100-01-01     006          
         8          5 100-01-01-271 100-01-01     271          
...
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fe2f0b1a1f3e831a10ba5dd73a5aa436)

In principle, if this is a real hierarchy, you only need to store the ID, parent ID and leaf part, and can then reconstruct the whole account with a hierarchical query (or recursive CTE). That may not actually be practical, or sensible, for your situation.

---

Looking at the edit history of your question, it seems like your table has an empty `h_id` column that you want to populate. You can use the same mechanism with a correlated update:

```
update your_table t1
set h_id = (
  select t2.id
  from your_table t2
  where t2.account = substr(t1.account, 1, instr(t1.account, '-', -1, 1) - 1)
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2a372ef0a035f763e06f2fce814f6487)